# awtPixelAttributesIntRGB3 cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, opengl

i update the opengl version.

But i got an error :

```
           AWTGLPixelBuffer pixelBuffer = pixelBufferProvider.allocate(gl,
            AWTGLPixelBuffer.awtPixelAttributesIntRGB3,
            v.getWidth(),
            v.getHeight(),
            1,
            true,
            0);
```

My library could not find `awtPixelAttributesIntRGB3` . If i use old version, it can find that.

I import the same library : `import com.jogamp.opengl.util.awt.AWTGLPixelBuffer;`

Last thing, i downloaded last version of opengl here (jogamp-all-platforms.7z) : 
http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-current/archive/

And i only add **jogamp-all.jar** to my lib folder.

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You give us very little information on what's going on.
E.g. we don't even know from what version to which new one you upgraded.

I guess your problem is that the field `awtPixelAttributesIntRGB3` was removed from version `2.2` to `2.3`.
The [API documentation of GLPixelBuffer.GLPixelBufferProvider#allocate](https://jogamp.org/deployment/v2.3.0/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/com/jogamp/opengl/util/GLPixelBuffer.GLPixelBufferProvider.html#allocate%28com.jogamp.opengl.GL,%20com.jogamp.nativewindow.util.PixelFormat.Composition,%20com.jogamp.opengl.util.GLPixelBuffer.GLPixelAttributes,%20boolean,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) explains quite well how to use it.
The key is that you need to fetch `pixelAttributes` differently, e.g. via `getAttributes(GL, int, boolean)`.